# Cycle.js/xstream click event streamed once, but fired twice

Tags: cyclejs, xstream-js

There's a single button element on the page and the following click stream:

```
let submitClick$ = sources.DOM.select(buttonSel)
  .events("click")
  .mapTo(true)
  .debug(console.log)
```

Once I click on the button, `true` is logged, which is correct.

However, when I map the stream, the code inside runs twice:

```
let submitDeal$ = submitClick$.map(() => {
  console.log("Clicked")
  // ...
})
```

No other event handlers should be attached to the button, and the element itself sits inside a div:

```
button(".btn--add", "Submit")
```

The usual `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't make a difference, and inspecting the event does show that it is fired from the same element `button.btn--add`.

Not really sure what's going on, any ideas are appreciated! Thanks!

Versions:

```
"@cycle/dom": "^12.2.5"
"@cycle/http": "^11.0.1"
"@cycle/xstream-run": "^3.1.0"
"xstream": "^6.4.0"
```

**Update 1:** I triple checked and no JS files are loaded twice. I'm using Webpack that bundles a single `app.js` file that's loaded on the page (Elixir/Phoenix app). Also when inspecting the button in the `Event Listeners` tab in Chrome's Developer Tools, it seems that only 1 event handled is attached.

**Update 2:** [Gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/svileng/36cc443f6cc94f9f1b6c01a98d14861d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to a bug in xstream, which was fixed in `xstream@7.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Too little information is given to resolve this problem. However some things come to mind:

You shouldn't use `.debug(console.log)` but `.debug(x => console.log(x))` instead. In fact `.debug()` is enough, it will use console.log internally.

Then, is the button inside a `<form>`? That may be affecting the events. In general this question needs more details.

Comment: Thank you for having a look, André! I edited my post and added a link to a gist with the source (with some logic omitted for brevity): https://gist.github.com/svileng/36cc443f6cc94f9f1b6c01a98d14861d. If there is anything else I can provide in the question, let me know. Thank you!